# Числа с плавающей точкой

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Не переваривает это выражение, в чем дело?

```
Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text.Trim(), "^[^\d\.]$")
```

Comment: Как альтернатива - Double.TryParse()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

^([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)$

http://regex101.com/r/uR2jZ5

Comment: Сайт хорош, спасибо за наводку!

Comment: За сайт благодарен больше, чем за решение х)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, сам на Хэше узнал о нем, как и о многих других))

Answer (score 4):

Зачем стоит " ^ " в скобках? Получается, что это "не десятичная цифра с точкой"

Моя версия будет такой для десятичных значений через точку:

```
^(\+|\-)?\d+(\.\d+)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, как-то так (эксперты конечно могут и лучше написать)

[-+]?[0-9]*[,]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]*

http://regex101.com/r/pG5bG3 (за сайт спс)